# Where-object $_ matches multiple criterias

Tags: powershell

```
$data|where-object{$_.Name -eq "$serverName.domain.com"}|select-object -Property Description1, Version | where-object{$_.Description1 -match "bnx2x" -or "be2net"} | %{"{0}" -f $_.Version}
```

So I'm trying to get the version number. However, the Description1 can have two names that I want to look for. I've gotten my code to work for just matching one string but I cant seem to find the right syntax to match multiple strings with an "-or"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do what you want, and is a bit shorter than what you originally had.

```
$data | Where-Object{
  $_.Name -eq "$serverName.chrobinson.com" -and (
     $_.Description1 -match "bnx2x" -or
     $_.Description1 -match "be2net"
  )
} | Select-Object -expand version
```

You just needed `$_.Description1 -match "bnx2x" -or $_.Description1 -match "be2net"` really, but I think this is easier to read than what you had.

Comment: Thank you. That does exactly what I need. Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me and elaborating ~ appreciate it

Comment: I have a related question to this example: Let's say the strings that shall be matched are replaced by variables that are passed in through a function. Can you think of a scenario that only the first, second variable are honored in the "-or" part? Maybe I have to open a separate question for this, but did not find a way to ask a question that is related to this one.

Comment: @user637338 Sorry to be so very late responding. I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you saying that "bnx2x" and "be2net" are replaced by variables that are defined previously by a function? Or are you trying to only get the first two matches? You may be better off asking a separate question to better define things.

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively:

```
$data|
where-object{ ($_.Name -eq "$serverName.chrobinson.com") -and
              ($_.Description1 -match 'bnx2x|be2net') } | 
select -ExpandProperty Version
```