# Azure NSG rules exposed to internet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-nsg

I am creating one PS script which fetch all ports that are allowed to internet in Azure NSG, here problem is i want to get by port number in the below script i am able to fetch only one port but how to fetch for multiple ports.

Currently i am fetching 443 at the same time i want to fetch for 80 and 8443, can can i write logic in
-eq condition on below script

```
$subscriptions = 'xxxxxxx'
foreach ($azsub in $subscriptions)
{
set-AzContext -subscription $azsub
$aznsgs = Get-AzNetworksecuritygroup
 foreach ($aznsg in $aznsgs)
  { 
    Get-Aznetworksecurityruleconfig -networksecuritygroup $aznsg | Where-Object { $_.DestinationPortRange -eq "443"  | Select-object `
                   @{label = 'NSG name'   ; expression = {$aznsg.name}}, ` 
                   @{label = 'Rulename'   ; expression = {$_.name}} , `
                   @{label = 'Port Range' ; expression = {$_.destinationportrange}} , 'access' , 'priority' , 'direction', `
                   @{label = 'RG name'    ; expression = {$aznsg.resourcegroupname}`
         } | Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\NSG.CSV" -NoTypeInformation -Append
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your where clause to include all of them.

```
Where-Object { ($_.DestinationPortRange -eq "443" -or $_.DestinationPortRange -eq "80" -or $_.DestinationPortRange -eq "8443")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple conditions in the where.
Here is a similar post
[Where-object $_ matches multiple criterias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896345/where-object-matches-multiple-criterias/23896434)

The example from the post

```
data | Where-Object{
  $_.Name -eq "$serverName.chrobinson.com" -and (
     $_.Description1 -match "bnx2x" -or
     $_.Description1 -match "be2net"
  )
} | Select-Object -expand version
```