# Powershell .Where() method with multiple properties

Tags: powershell

I have a GenericList of Hashtables, and I need to test for the existence of a record based on two properties. In my hash table, I have two records that share one property value, but are different on another property value.
Specifically, `DisplayName` of both is `Autodesk Content for Revit 2023`
But `UninstallString` for one is `MsiExec.exe /X{GUID}` while the other is `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AdODIS\V1\Installer.exe followed by a few hundred characters of other info`

I want to select only the one with `AdODIS` in the `UninstallString`. And I would like to do it without a loop, and specifically using the `.Where()` method rather than the pipeline and `Where-Object`.
There are also MANY other records.

I CAN select just based on one property, like this...

```
$rawKeys.Where({$_.displayName -eq 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023'})
```

And I get the appropriate two records returned. However, when I try expanding that to two properties with different criteria, like this...

```
$rawKeys.Where({($_.displayName -eq 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023') -and ($_.uninstallString -like 'MsiExec.exe*')})
```

nothing is returned. I also tried chaining the `.Where()` calls, like this...

```
$rawKeys.Where({$_.displayName -eq 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023'}).Where({$_.uninstallString -like 'MsiExec.exe*'})
```

and again, nothing returned.
just to be sure the second condition is working, I tried...

```
$rawKeys.Where({$_.uninstallString -like 'MsiExec.exe*'})
```

and got multiple records returned, as expected.

I found [this][1] that talk about doing it with `Where-Object`, and applying that approach to the method was my first attempt. But I have yet to see either an example of doing it with `.Where()` or something specifically saying `.Where()` is limited to one conditional.

So, am I just doing something wrong? Or is this actually not possible with `.Where()` and I have no choice but to use the pipeline? And there I would have thought based on that link that some variation on...

```
$rawKeys | Where-Object {(($_.displayName -eq 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023') -and ($_.uninstallString -like 'MsiExec.exe*'))}
```

would work, but that's failing too.

I also tried...

```
$rawKeys.Where({$_.displayName -eq 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023'}) -and $rawKeys.Where({$_.uninstallString -like 'MsiExec.exe*'})
```

And THAT returns true, which for my current need is enough, but one: I would like to know if it can be done in a single method call, and two: I can imagine I will eventually want to get the record(s) back, rather than just a bool. Which is only possible with the single method call.

EDIT: OK, this is weird. I tried doing a minimal example of actual data, like this...

```
$rawKeys = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Hashtable]
$rawKeys.Add(@{
    displayName = 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023'
    uninstallString = 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AdODIS\V1\Installer.exe whatever else is here'
    guid = '{019AEF66-C054-39BB-88AD-B2D8EA9BE40A}'
})
$rawKeys.Add(@{
    displayName = 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023'
    uninstallString = 'MsiExec.exe /X{205C6D76-2023-0057-B227-DC6376F702DC}'
    guid = '{205C6D76-2023-0057-B227-DC6376F702DC}'
})
```

and that WORKS. So somewhere in my real code I am changing the data, and for the life of me I can't see where it's happening. But it's happening. The ACTUAL data comes from the registry, with this code...

```
$uninstallKeyPaths = @('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall', 
                       'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')
$rawKeys = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Hashtable]
$localMachineHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, 0)

foreach ($uninstallKeyPath in $uninstallKeyPaths) {
    foreach ($uninstallKeyName in $localMachineHive.OpenSubKey($uninstallKeyPath).GetSubKeyNames()) {
        if ($uninstallKeyPath -like '*Wow6432Node*') {
            $bitness = 'x32'
        } else {
            $bitness = 'x64'
        }
        $uninstallKey = $localMachineHive.OpenSubKey("$uninstallKeyPath\$uninstallKeyName")
        if (($displayName = $uninstallKey.GetValue('DisplayName')) -and ($displayVersion = $uninstallKey.GetValue('DisplayVersion')) -and 
            (($installDate = $uninstallKey.GetValue('InstallDate')) -or ($uninstallString = $uninstallKey.GetValue('UninstallString')))) {

            $keyName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($uninstallKey.Name)

            $keyData = @{
                displayName = $displayName
                displayVersion = $displayVersion
                guid = "$(if ($keyName -match $pattern.guid) {$keyName})" #$Null
                publisher = $uninstallKey.GetValue('Publisher')
                uninstallString = $uninstallString
                installDate = $installDate
                properties = (@($uninstallKey.GetValueNames()) | Sort-Object) -join ', '
                type = $bitness
            }
            [void]$rawKeys.Add($keyData)
        }
    }
}
```

So, meaningless unless you actually have Autodesk Revit 2023 installed on your machine, but maybe someone sees where I am changing the data.
[1]: [Where-object $_ matches multiple criterias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896345/where-object-matches-multiple-criterias)

Comment: Tbh, I'm unable to reproduce, I tried your actual code and filtering with 2 or more conditions is working fine for me. If you do `$rawKeys.uninstallstring` are you sure you see `msiexec` there ? Maybe you're filtering something you think is there when it's actually not

Comment: Yeah, I am sure it's there, I can iterate through the data and see what I expect. And as I mentioned, if I ONLY filter for UninstallString I get what's expected. It only fails when I try to filter on two criteria.

Comment: `$rawKeys.Where({$_.displayName -eq 'Autodesk Content for Revit 2023'}).uninstallString.GetType()` does this return `string` or `object[]` ?

Comment: Found it! It's because I am populating variables in the conditional like so `if (($displayName = $uninstallKey.GetValue('DisplayName')) ...`. On the next loop there might not be a property, but that doesn't seem to null the variable, it stays the old value, so SOME of the data is getting corrupted.

Comment: So, SOME of the UninstallString values where not what I was expecting at all. And it just happened that it was something totally unrelated to either condition I might look for.

Comment: `=` is an assignment. Your test should be `if (($displayName -eq $uninstallKey.GetValue('DisplayName'))`

Comment: @Theo I was being too tricksy for my own good, and trying to do the assignment at the same time as the conditional. I saw that approach once in a thread here, and thought it was pretty slick. Coming around to the idea that more lines and less trickery is actually better in the lonmg run. :)